# How to format a write statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data that I want to print to file. For missing data, I wish to print the mean of the actual data. However, the mean is calculated to more than the required 4 decimal places. How can I write to the mean to file and format this mean at the same time?

I have tried the following, but keep getting errors:

```
outfile.write('{0:%.3f}'.format(str(mean))+"\n")
```

Comment: What errors are you getting ?

Comment: ValueError: Invalid conversion specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove the `%` since it makes your format syntax invalid.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> '{:%.3f}'.format(1.2345)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification
>>> '{:.3f}'.format(1.2345)
'1.234'
>>>
```

Second, don't put `mean` in `str` since `str.format` is expecting a float (that's what the `f` in the format syntax represents).  Below is a demonstration of this bug:

```
>>> '{:.3f}'.format('1.2345')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
>>> '{:.3f}'.format(1.2345)
'1.234'
>>>
```

Third, the `+"\n"` is unnecessary since you can put the `"\n"` in the string you used on `str.format`.

Finally, as shown in my demonstrations, you can remove the `0` since it is redundant.

---

In the end, the code should be like this:

```
outfile.write('{:.3f}\n'.format(mean))
```

Comment: Problem with "f" now unfortunately. I'm guessing the string conversion is a problem too.

Comment: @stars83clouds - Oh yes, I missed that. You need to not convert mean to a string.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to string using str(). Also, the "%" is not required. Just use:

```
outfile.write('{0:.3f}'.format(mean)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the formatting of your string has nothing to do with your write statement. You can reduce your problem to:

```
string = '{0:%.3f}'.format(str(mean))+"\n"
outfile.write(string)
```

Then, your string specification is incorrect and should be:

```
string = '{0:.3f}\n'.format(mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile.write('{.3f}\n'.format(mean))
```